# Extract a screenshot from video in GStreamer?

Tags: video, gstreamer

How do I extract a screenshot (image) at specific time from a video, using *GStreamer*?

I want to extract the screenshot somewhere at the middle of a movie. i.e. If the video is 60 seconds, I would like to extract the screenshot at 00:00:30 .

The video length is unknown at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source code for `totem-video-thumbnailer`: http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/tree/src/totem-video-thumbnailer.c